# Iionic - clickable search bar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, searchbar

Is there a way to restrict a search bar so that it would react to a tap / click and not show the keyboard?

I am trying to mimic the google maps functionality where

- the user taps on the bar
- a new view / modal opens and with a new bar
- the search bar keyboard opens then. Of

  course G Maps is more efficiently implemented and all done in one smooth procedure.

What I have right now as a working solution is

- tap on bar1
- keyboard opens while new view loads
- keyboard closes
- must tap on bar2 in new view to open keyboard

this is bad UX. How can I streamline this with Ionic without bar1 opening the keyboard and trigger bar2 keyboard when view opens.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `ion-navbar` put an `ion-input`:

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-input placeholder="Search..." (ionFocus)="openSearchModal()" readonly>
        <ion-icon name="md-mic"></ion-icon>
    </ion-input>
</ion-navbar>
```

Set the input as read-only and bind a function when the user clicks the input to open the search modal.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Now, how would I open the keyboard for the search bar in the next view when it opens?

Comment: If you're going to user a searcbar in the modal page you can get the searchbar with @ViewChild(Searchbar) searchbar: Searchbar

and then you can do this.searchbar.setFocus(). This will only work for Android